# how to load selected data from a table view when a segment is selected?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I wanted to know how to load selected data from my table view, for example when selecting segment index is equal 1, the table view will reload and will only show data which status is equal to approved. Cause as you have seen from my below code, I have loaded all the data with all the statuses: . for example if segmentView.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 table will reload with the data which status is equal to approved. I could already determine the selected index. what i want is how to access those data from the table view that i could load selected data depending to status

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
        let cellIdentifier = "ToDoListTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ToDoListTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self


//        let toDoActionItem = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

        if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row] {
            print("ang tanan data:" , getTempDetails)
            if let str = getTempDetails["status"] as? [String: String] {
                if let name = str["name"] {
                    if name == "ongoing" {
                        cell.toDoItemLabel.text = getTempDetails["name"] as? String
                        cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = created
//                        cell.label.textColor =  UIColor(red: 0.9294, green: 0.3333, blue: 0.1804, alpha: 1.0)
//                        cell.backgroundColor = created


                    }
                    else if name == "approved" {
                       cell.toDoItemLabel.text = getTempDetails["name"] as? String
                       cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = done
                       cell.checkBoxButton.isSelected =  true
                    }
                    else if name == "for approval" {
                        cell.toDoItemLabel.text = getTempDetails["name"] as? String
                        cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = pending
                    }else if name == "near expiry" {
                       cell.toDoItemLabel.text = getTempDetails["name"] as? String
                        cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = neardue
                    } else if name == "expired" {
                        cell.toDoItemLabel.text = getTempDetails["name"] as? String
                        cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = expired
                    } else {
                        print("false")
                       cell.toDoItemLabel.text = "LOLS"
                    }
                }
                }
            }



    code for segment (in selecting segment)

    func selectSegmentInSegmentView(segmentView: SMSegmentView) {

        if segmentView.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            print("ang index nga emo ge click is one")
            //            let selectedSegment : SMSegment = segmentView.selectedSegment!
            //            self.userName = selectedSegment.label.text!

        } else {

            logic here
        }
        self.setUpTableView()
or could be self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Is your issue about filtering only "approved"/"expired" or about the TableView? I'd use a "selectedDetailsArray" that will get the `getAllDetail` filtered according to the segmentedControl choice, and use only this one for the datasource (numberOfRows, cellForRow, etc.)

Comment: what i want is for example segmentView.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 table will load data which status is equal to approved for example.

Comment: Do you have 5 segments in segment control named ongoing, approved, for approval, near expiry and expired?

Comment: yeah indexes is equal to number of status

Comment: @DurnKurvirck Can you please explain a bit more abt the code.? And come to the chat from yesterday we can discuss there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create 5 separate arrays to load while selection of different segment of `UISegmentControl`.

```
var ongoingArr = [[String: Any]]() // For segment index 0
var approvedArr = [[String: Any]]() // For segment index 1
var forApprovalArr = [[String: Any]]() // For segment index 2
var nearExpiryArr = [[String: Any]]() // For segment index 3
var expiredArr = [[String: Any]]() // For segment index 4
```

You have the whole data `getAllDetail`, and you are getting the data in this array by API or previous screen:

```
var getAllDetail = [[String: Any]]()
```

> If you are getting the data from API, then load above 5 arrays after loading the data in `getAllDetail`. Fo that just create an extension of array as:

```
extension Array where Element == [String: Any] {

    func filterArray(_ statusName: String) -> [Element] {
        return self.filter { infoDict -> Bool in
            if let statusDict = infoDict["status"] as? [String: String], let name = statusDict["name"] {
                return name == statusName
            }
            return false
        }
    }

}
```

**and, load above 5 arrays:**

```
func loadSegmentArray() {

    ongoingArr = getAllDetail.filterArray("ongoing")
    approvedArr = getAllDetail.filterArray("approved")
    forApprovalArr = getAllDetail.filterArray("for approval")
    nearExpiryArr = getAllDetail.filterArray("near expiry")
    expiredArr = getAllDetail.filterArray("expired")

    // Select 0th index of segment and reload table
    segmentView.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    self.setUpTableView() // Reload Table view
}
```

In your func `selectSegmentInSegmentView`, just reload table view:

```
func selectSegmentInSegmentView(segmentView: SMSegmentView) {
    self.setUpTableView()
}
```

> And update your `UITabelView` delegate and datasource methods, according to these 5 arrays.
>
> **For Sample, I am writing `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt indexPath`:**

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch segmentView.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        return ongoingArr.count
    case 1:
        return approvedArr.count
    case 2:
        return forApprovalArr.count
    case 3:
        return nearExpiryArr.count
    case 4:
        return expiredArr.count
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "ToDoListTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ToDoListTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self

    var infoDict = [String: Any]()
    switch segmentView.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        infoDict = ongoingArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = // Color of onging
    case 1:
        infoDict = approvedArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = // Color of approvedArr
    case 2:
        infoDict = forApprovalArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = // Color of forApprovalArr
    case 3:
        infoDict = nearExpiryArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = // Color of nearExpiryArr
    case 4:
        infoDict = expiredArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = // Color of expiredArr
    default:
        cell.statuslabel.backgroundColor = .black
    }

    cell.toDoItemLabel.text = infoDict["name"] as? String
    return cell
}
```

Comment: i am getting the data from an API

Comment: In response of API, load `getAllDetail` first then call a method in which load all 5 arrays and set selected segment index = 0 then reload table

Comment: Can you open a chat , so i can clarify through there

Comment: I created a function `loadSegmentArray` call this in response of API success after loading `getAllDetail`

Comment: I am not able to find chat option, I am bit new on stack overflow.

Comment: oh i see , okay2x

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169213/discussion-between-ankit-jayaswal-and-durn-kurvirck).

Answer (score 1):

**The best option Would be like:**

make a common `array` for Display, that will be used to display the data in `tableView`:

and the Use it like this for all the conditions like:

make a Common Function like this:

```
   func filterDataStatusWise(strStatus:String){

    for dict in arrMainResponse{

        let strStatus = arrMainResponse["status"]

        if strStatus["name"] = strStatus{
            //Whatever data add in arrForDisplay here
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And then Use it like this:

```
var arrForDisplay = [String:Any]()

if condition1{
        filterDataStatusWise(strStatus: "ongoing")
    }else if condition2{
        filterDataStatusWise(strStatus: "approved")
    }else if condition3{
        filterDataStatusWise(strStatus: "for approval")
    }else if condition4{
        filterDataStatusWise(strStatus: "near expiry")
    }else{
        filterDataStatusWise(strStatus: "expired")
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey Sir are you there?

Comment: @DurnKurvirck I am back in the Chats section, we can continue there

Answer (score 0):

Filter array with respect to selected index(status):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
Int) -> Int {

    switch segmentView.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        if self.expiredArray == nil {
            return 0
        }
        return (self.expiredArray?.count)!   
    case 1:
        if self.approvedArray == nil {
            return 0
        }
        return (self.complaintArray?.count)!
    default:
        break
    }
    return 0

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch segmentView.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
    // Load from expired array
    case 1:
    // Load from approved array
    default:
        break
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

func selectSegmentInSegmentView(segmentView: SMSegmentView) {
   if segmentView.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
   // Write your code to filter array here based on status
   } else {
   // Write your code to filter array here based on status
   }
// reload tableview here.....

}
```